# Make API call with argument set in useState just before it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React app I initialize the `sortInComponent` object to the values below using `useState`.

```
const [sortInComponent, setSortInComponent] = useState({
    sortBy: 'price',
    sortOrder: 'asc'
});
```

Then the value of `sortInComponent` is changed when I click on a label:

```
<label htmlFor='' onClick={() => {
    setCurrentPage(1);
    sortInComponent.sortOrder === 'asc'
        ? setSortInComponent({ sortBy: 'timestamp', sortOrder: 'desc' })
        : setSortInComponent({ sortBy: 'timestamp', sortOrder: 'asc' });

    getRecordsForPage(1, nameFilter, min, max, startDate, endDate, resultsPerPage, sortInComponent);    
}}>...</label>
```

By the way the app behaves and what is logged to the console it seems the `getRecordsForPage` call is made before the `sortInComponent` value is updated.
How do I call `getRecordsForPage` with the new value of `sortInComponent`?

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/ElAnonimo/job-fullstack/blob/master/client/src/components/Records.js.

Comment: You could do nothing after setSortInComponent and run an effect with useEffect when sirtInComponent state changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useEffect hook.
You first change the state the way you are doing it, and then, once it's changed, call the useEffect, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getRecordsForPage(...)
}, [sortInComponent])
```

By adding your state into the dependency array, every time it changes the useEffect call is going to be triggered.

[More on useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)